# If I can call SomeClass with some_class, then how can I call Module::SomeClass?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Post is accessible via

```
Blog.first.posts
```

How do I do this with a module name space? Such as Engine::Post

```
Blog.first.???
```

Thanks

Comment: We will need more information about the environment that's running on. Is it Rails? How are you creating the relationship between the Blog and the Post?

Comment: Okay, I'm using rails 3.1. The relationship between the two is that a blog embeds_many posts using Mongoid. The blog is being extracted out into an engine which namespaces each class with the name of my engine therefore isolating the namespace for routing purposes.

Comment: So Blog becomes Engine::Blog and Post Engine::Post. If I don't supply the namespace then I get an uninitialized constant error on Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly giving Mongoid the class name

```
class Engine::Blog
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :posts, :class_name => "Engine::Post"
end
```